# How to apply react-markdown in a div in React

Tags: reactjs, markdown

How to can i apply react-markdown in a div in React

```
<div id="chats">
</div>
```

i want to apply ReactMarkdown in this Div

```
<ReactMarkdown>
    <div id="chats">
    </div>
</ReactMarkdown>
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: i want markdown functionality in my chat app in react

Comment: like in  whatsapp when we press * Some Text * text shows in a Bold font

Comment: is there any other approach to do this?